# How can I spawn multiple of the same robot, and control them individually?

Tags: ros, spawn-model, namespace, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I'm using Indigo for a project involving swarms of robots.
I want to be able to spawn and control multiple of the same URDF into Gazebo. I've been attempting to use the RRBot (from this tutorial: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control) for this purpose.

I open Gazebo with one RRBot as such:

**roslaunch rrbot_gazebo rrbot_world.launch**

And then are able to control it with the topics that this line loads in:

**roslaunch rrbot_control rrbot_control.launch**

However, if I load more RRBots into the simulation with different model names and namespaces as with:

**rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file `rospack find rrbot_description`/urdf/rrbot.xml -urdf -y 1 -model rrbot2 -robot_namespace rrbot2**

There are: a) No topics displayed with which to control the newly spawned rrbot2, b) Naming conflicts such as the one below:

**[ERROR] [1469970215.112663786,
27.972000000]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/rrbot/controller_manager/list_controllers]**

Is there a way to spawn multiple of the same URDF that can be independently controlled and not cause conflicts?
Any feedback would be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240748/how-can-i-spawn-multiple-of-the-same-robot,-and-control-them-individually?/) by [RHolland](https://answers.ros.org/users/27644/rholland/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This repository has an excellent demo of a robot swarm:
https://github.com/nevinvalsaraj/swarm-gazebo-simulator

It uses an SDF so works well with Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [RHolland](https://answers.ros.org/users/27644/rholland/) with karma: 16 on 2016-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0